# Remove (replace) link with class="selected" and attributes but keep anchor using PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, menu, hyperlink

I'm looking for a good regex which would remove link with class="selected" from a menu. The problem is that my links have other attributes such as rel, title.
Example of such link

```
<a class="selected" href="http://domain.org/connect.html" title="About Us, Contact us" rel="nofollow">About us</a>
```

All code works. I have tried with a simple test regex. But it does not work correctly. Also `<a class="selected".*?>([^>]*)<\/a>/i` doesn't work. I need a strong regex, I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: i suggest use `DOMDOcument` instead

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<a[^>]*class="selected"[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>
```

?

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/iM8pJ9/1)